# sSet is a model for Martin-lof type theory

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, constructive-mathematics

Simplicial sets category sSet satisfies the univalent axiom this is theorem now;with some large cardinal hypothesis. 
My question, Is sSet a model for Martin-lof typ theory by this theorem? any reference would be helpful.

Comment: what is the univalent axiom? In what sense do you mean that sSet is a model for constructive mathematics? as a topos?

Comment: I mean, Voevodsky's univalent axiom and Martin-Lof's constructive mathematics

Comment: Sorry, as a topo

Comment: Homotopy type theory is an extension of Martin–Löf type theory, so I suppose the answer is yes in principle...

Comment: @ZhenLin:do you mean that; Martin-lof type theory does not need strong hypothesis

Comment: According to [Streicher](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~streicher/sstt.pdf), "simplicial sets organize into a model of Martin-Löf type theory. Moreover, we explain Voevodsky's
Univalence Axiom which holds in this model and implements the idea that isomorphic types are identical as suggested in [HS]." But my point was that any model of homotopy type theory is in particular a model of intensional Martin-Löf type theory.

Comment: @ZhenLin:I think my question is wrong;because ( Martin-lof type theory +Univalence Axiom) is a type theory stronger than Martin-lof type theory and sSet is a model of Martin-lof type theory without the need to large cardinal   hypothesis; but we need large cardinal hypothesis with the   stronger type theory.

Comment: This is what I understood from you? is this right?

Comment: I don't know. As I understand it, the large cardinal hypothesis is used to show that $\textbf{sSet}$ has universe types, and also to get around the problem of functoriality for substitution.

Comment: I will read Streicher's paper,could you tell me about more papers that explain these "universe types" and "problem of functoriality for substitution" for sSet category

Comment: @ZhenLin: Great paper,thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this article: http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.2553

The univalence axiom is phrased in Martin-Löf type theory. So yes, they demonstrate that the simplicial sets form a model of MLTT and moreover it models univalence.